# How to Check Whether a Variable Used in a Target Defined in an External File Is Set

Tags: makefile, sh, gnu-make

Here's my `msbuild.mk`...

```
# default build configuration
CONFIGURATION = Release

.PHONY: check-env build-app

check-env: ## Check build environment
    [ -v APP_NAME ] && $(error APP_NAME not set)
    [ -v APP_SRCDIR ] && $(error APP_SRCDIR not set)
    [ -v APP_OUTRDIR ] && $(error APP_OUTDIR not set)

build-app: check-env ## Build .NET application
    @msbuild ${APP_SRCDIR}/${APP_NAME}.sln -t:Build \
        -p:BaseIntermediateOutputPath=${APP_OUTDIR}/obj/ \
        -p:OutDir=${APP_OUTDIR}/bin/ \
        -p:Configuration=${CONFIGURATION}
```

... and here I've included it into my actual `Makefile`:

```
include ./msbuild.mk

SRCDIR = src

APP_NAME = MyApp
APP_SRCDIR = ${SRCDIR}/code/${APP_NAME}
APP_OUTDIR = ${OUTDIR}/${APP_NAME}

.DEFAULT_GOAL = build-app
```

When I try this...

```
make build-app
```

... the `check-env` target in `msbuild.mk` aborts the script saying the variables are not set (even they are set in the actual `Makefile`). Furthermore, if I remove the `check-env` target, the `build-app` target succeeds as variables `APP_NAME`, `APP_SRCDIR`, and `APP_OUTDIR` seem to be set correctly.

I'm a bit lost... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

First, the **-v** option to test is not a POSIX standard option; it's a bash extension.  Make will always invoke `/bin/sh` as the shell which may or may not actually be bash, depending on your system.  If all you care about is whether the variable has a non-empty value or not you can use `[ -n "$VAR" ]` instead.

Second, you can't intersperse make functions like `$(error ...)` with shell operations like `test`.  If you think about it there's no way that can work: make doesn't have a shell interpreter embedded in it, it expands the command, runs a real shell process, and waits for the exit code to know if it worked.  How can a condition that is handled by the *shell* control whether or not a *make* function like `$(error ...)` is run or not?

If you want to test shell variables you have to use shell commands to handle the error, something like this:

```
check-env: ## Check build environment
        [ -n "$$APP_NAME" ] || { echo APP_NAME not set; exit 1; }
```

If you just want to check for *make* variables being set, you can do it more straightforwardly using make syntax.  Something like:

```
check-env = $(foreach V,APP_NAME,APP_SOURCEDIR,APP_OUTDIR, \
              $(if $($V),,$(error Variable $V is not set)))

build-app:
        $(check-env)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, It works! Just to let you know, I had to use `[ -n "${APP_NAME}" ]` instead of `[ -n "$$APP_NAME" ]`.

Comment: Your change means you're checking that the _make_ variable is set properly.  I thought you wanted to check that the shell _environment variable_ is set properly.  If you just want to check the make variable why even bother creating a rule that has to be listed as a prerequisite and runs a shell to do the check?  Why not just check it in make itself?

Comment: I'm just creating a set of prebuilt make targets... and in this case I wanted to ensure that when importing `msbuild` the `Makefile` defines the required variables. Long story short, building a `mono` project just requires importing `msbuild.mk` and define the 3 `APP_` variables. That's it :-)